# How to measure reflected light from 3D model in blender

Tags: python, light, lighting, lightprobe

- We have a simple 3D model of the body (like cube or sphere), with texture parameters like Glossy BSDF, so the body can reflect light.
- The body is lighted by a light source (Sun).

scene example on the figure below

[image: Scene example]

Is there a way to measure light reflected from the 3D model (in some units...Flux, candles, no matter what) in the position of the camera?
If YES, can this be done by python scripting?

Comment: The only way was to generate video and get a Flux of frames

Answer (score 2):

If you use Cycles, save the output in EXR format; then, the units will be radiance in W/m<sup>2</sup>/sr. See: [EXR output units](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/198900/exr-output-units).