# How to measure reflected/scattered light intensity (Irradiance) from a surface at any 3D location?

Tags: modeling

I am looking for a way in blender to measure the intensity of light (in W/m2) reaching a point in space after reflecting from a diffuse object (a complex shape like a plant/shrub). The ultimate goal is to design a hardware light sensor system that can measure the reflected intensity of light from an object illuminated by the sun (or any light source).
I plan to vary its angle (to simulate time of day) and estimate the total light intensity reaching a light sensor placed at a distance and pointed at the object.
Is there any way to do this (i.e. place a light probe/sensor in blender or use the camera itself somehow)? I'm not looking for accuracy in the exact value, but the overall relative variation in reflected/scattered/diffuse light from the object versus the angle of the sunlight. I see a similar [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/205417/how-to-measure-reflected-light-from-3d-model-in-blender) posted in 2017 but there are no answers. Thanks in advance!

P.S. I imagine it can also be useful for modeling things like the power received by a solar panel with respect to time of day, etc.